# Does Eclipse use ant build system by default?

Tags: eclipse, ant, build-system

I see a .classpath file in eclipse project, it seems not a ant build description file. so by default, does eclipse use ant to build it's project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You can have it create an Ant buildfile by right clicking the project in the project explorer and then going to Export --> Ant Buildfile, but Eclipse doesnt use it by default.

Comment: Can you tell how the default build system for android project in Eclipse is called ?